# how to make java desktop application to mobile application

Tags: java, windows-mobile, mobile-application

I have developed one desktop application using netbeans 7.3 ,JDK 1.7. How can i make this application as a mobile application(that can be run in mobile device , or at least how can i run this application on windows phone). Please provide some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends very strongly on what you used in your desktop application and what mobile platforms you want to port it to. Windows Phone should be difficult, as Java is not one of the supported programming languages. Android would probably be easier, though still likely a lot of work. And if you're talking J2ME, well, that too will be a lot of work.

When it comes to pure non graphical Java (J2SE with no external libraries and no Swing or AWT) a lot of it will work easily on on an Android or J2ME phone. You will have to completely rewrite the gui though, using the gui elements offered by the framework you're using. There are however things that will not work, as both Android and J2ME implement subsets of the built in libraries offered in the full JDK.

If you use external libraries that can be difficult. You can be lucky and they either work on Android/J2ME natively or there are versions for those systems. But if you're not lucky then you'll have to look for alternatives.

**TL;DR** On Windows Phone you'll probably have to rewrite it in a different language. For Android/J2ME some parts may be usable.